# Jenkins is not starting the build upon SQS message arrival

Tags: build, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, amazon-sqs

*Tools:*

- Jenkins version 1.506
- GitHub
- GitHub SQS Plugin 1.4

Jenkins configured to consume the messages and GitHub for sending them over Amazon SQS (set the active key and secret key and queue name).  Also configured for modules with "Build when a message is published to an SQS Queue"
The messages are sent by GitHub and consumed by Jenkins as warranted. I can see SQS Activity in Jenkins (see below) but for some reason Jenkins does not trigger the build.

I wonder what are we missing?

Last SQS Activity

> Started on Mar 20, 2013 3:03:49 AM Using strategy: Default [poll] Last
>   Build : #16 [poll] Last Built Revision: Revision
>   408d9c4d6412e44737b62f25e9c36fc8b3b074ca (origin/maple-sprint-4)
>   Fetching changes from the remote Git repositories Fetching upstream
>   changes from origin Polling for changes in Done. Took 1.3 sec Changes
>   found

Comment: this is a very difficult question to answer considering we know nothing about your project configuration...

Comment: what project configuration do you want me to elaborate about?

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing, did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had to set "Poll SCM" and set the period "* * * * *"  that did the trick!

Comment: Does this mean you have to poll the repo on GitHub every minute? Despite GitHub telling you via SQS that you have changes? Polling seems to defeat the purpose of setting the whole webhook-sqs-jenkins pipeline.